# Apple Push Notification - View Button Action

Tags: uiwebview, push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications

I have some problems with my Push Notifications. I can sent them well to my registered Devices. All works fine.

My Questions is: After clicking the VIEW button, the App is launching. At the moment without any content.

How can i add content here? This content should depend on the Push Notification i sent out.

For example: My Push Notification is about NEWS XYZ - then after clicking VIEW i should get more informations about NEWS XYZ

So i think i must get the news from my website. Perhabs with the ID they are posted on my side.
But how to implement this in the App?

I mean with every NEW Push Message, the must be shown the NEW News.

Also it should be possible to read all previous received NEWS in the App in a list, when getting back from NEWS Number 1.

You understand, what i mean?

I dont have any real idea...Would be nice if you can show me code regarding to an example.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push Notification - View Button action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015652/push-notification-view-button-action)

Answer (score 0):

This method invokes once you tap on the view button on the push notification,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
        if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
            // Application came from the background
            // Here you can request for the content
            // This has the value of your payload
            UILocalNotification *localNotif = (UILocalNotification *) [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

        }
        else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
                // Application is in the foreground
        }
 }
```

Comment: ok, but can you show me on an example, how to fill the NSDictionary. I read several tutorials, sites etc. nobody give me a example how it can work. i only get some code. but for me it is very important to see, how it will look or will work. at the moment i can not imagine...i mean i put in this code in Xcode and then?